# Modules not loaded on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem because my code does not work on the production server. When it comes to development environment, everything is fine. It looks like he doesn't read the classes. My ruby version is 2.6.6 and rails is set as 5.2.4.4.

*lib/crm/api.rb*

```rb
module CRM
  class API
    # some code
  end
end
```

*app/services/crm/changes.rb*

```rb
module CRM
  class Changes
    def initialize
      @api = API.new
    end
    # some code
  end
end
```

The main service is running as a cronjob.

*config/schedule.rb*

```rb
every 5.minutes do
  runner('CRM::CheckChanges.new.call', output: "#{path}/log/crm_check_changes.log")
end
```

And run this code

*app/services/crm/check_changes.rb*

```rb
module CRM
  class CheckChanges
    def initialize
      @changes = Changes.new
    end
    # some code
  end
end
```

At first I got errors log like 'Uninitialized constant CRM::Changes::API' after reload background jobs I got 'Unitialized constant CRM::API'

*config/application.rb*

```rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app)

Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('lib/**')).inject(config.autoload_paths){ |autoload_paths, path| autoload_paths << path }
```

As I mentioned before everything works fine on development environment. Does anyone have any idea what this could be about? Thanks in advance for answer.

Comment: Instead of using "autoload_paths", simply move your lib/crm/api.rb somewhere where it gets autoloaded properly, like app/lib, and then you can remove all three lines in the config, and your code should be autoloaded and reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `/lib` to the eager load paths as well:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

The default setting for production uses eager loading (all the classes are loaded at startup) instead of autoloading.

> In production, however, you want consistency and thread-safety and can
> live with a longer boot time. So eager_load is set to true, and then
> during boot (before the app is ready to receive requests) Rails loads
> all files in the eager_load_paths and then turns off auto loading (NB:
> autoloading may be needed during eager loading). Not autoloading after
> boot is a good thing, as autoloading can cause the app to have
> thread-safety problems.

See [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Classic Mode)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#autoload-paths-and-eager-load-paths). Also note that `/app` and all its subdirecties are already on the autoloading paths.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. Thanks!. Here it is described a bit more https://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/